# Connect function to an event

Tags: qt

I am trying to create an event handler that executes a function when the page load is done in the QWebView, the syntax i'm using is as follows:
`webview->connect(webview,SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)),this,SLOT(Load_Done()));`
This function is created and implemented in a class that i'm using other than the main class if this helps.
The problem is that i'm getting the following:
**No such slot QObject::Load_Finished()**

Answer (score 1):

It should be `QObject::connect(...)` not `webview->connect`. The rest looks fine as long as `Load_Done()` is defined.

**Edit:**

To make sure that signals and slots work properly, you need to declare your class that way:

```
class Facebook: QObject{

    Q_OBJECT

    public:

        // ...

    public slots:

        void Load_Done();

}
```

Comment: This is all the code related to the connect issue:  

`QObject::connect(webview,SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)),this,SLOT(Load_Done()));`  
  
And this is where i'm defining the slot in the class:  
`public slots:
    void Load_Done();`  
And this is the implementation of the Load_Done():  
`void Facebook::Load_Done()
{
    MainWindow * main=new MainWindow();
    main->ui->pushButton->setEnabled(true);
}`  
And the problem is still present.

Comment: Maybe you should try renaming `Load_Done()` to `Load_Done(bool ok)` to make it match the signal's signature. Also the `QObject::connect()` call is done from the Facebook class, right?

Comment: yes, it is done from the Facebook class  
As for the bool, i did try this as well and the problem still exists, however now i get a more reasonable error which is **No such slot QObject::Load_Done()**

Comment: Does your Facebook class inherits from QObject or QWidget? Did you add the macro `Q_OBJECT` at the top of the class declaration?

Comment: The class is declared as follows: **class Facebook: QObject{}**

Comment: You also need to add Q_OBJECT. I've updated my answer with the code.

Comment: This problem is solved but now for some reason the function is executed twice rather than once!!!  
Any idea why would this happen?

Comment: Try right-clicking on the project then select "Clean project" and rebuild. Maybe there's still some remains of the old code in the moc files.

Comment: tried this but the problem remains. The first time the function seems to be at the beginning of the project run and i guess it happens when the WebView is declared. the other is when the page is loaded.
So should the function get called when i define the QWebView??

Comment: That seems normal to me - the first time it probably loads a blank page and the second time, it loads your page. The signal is just emitted every time a page has finished loading. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I get you, but i'm loading the webview only once as follows:  
`webview=new QWebView(main);    
webview->resize(300,300);  
webview->move(30,30);  
webview->load(QUrl("https://www.google.com")_;`

Answer (score 0):

The signal and the slot have to have the same signature, e.g.:

```
connect(webview,SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)),this,SLOT(Load_Done(bool)));
```

Of course, LoadDone(bool) needs to exist in "this" and be a slot :)